# Linq query giving inappropriate output

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-group

I have two transaction tables named as **ParentTransaction** and **ChildTransaction** in which `TransactionId` of **ParentTransaction** will act as foreign to **ChildTransaction** of `TransactionId`.

Now I want to get all those TransactionId of ParentTransaction whose `payamount` is not completed.

From below output I want record of transaction Id 3 because only 1000 has been paid for `transactionid` 3 instead of 5000.

I have one table like this:

```
Transactionid(p.k)    PayAmount
  1                   1000
  2                   3000
  3                   5000
  4                   6000
```

ChildTransaction

```
Id        TransactionId(F.k)   DepositAmount
1           1                  600
2           1                  400
3           2                  1000
4           2                  1000
5           2                  1000
6           3                  2000
```

This is my query:

```
var data = (from tmp in context.ParentTransaction
            join tmp1 in context.ChildTransaction on tmp.Transactionid equals
            tmp1.Transactionid where tmp.PayAmount !=tmp1.DepositAmount
                    select tmp);
```

But here I am getting Transaction Id 1 and 2 although their transaction has been completed in two parts that is 600 and 400 for transaction id 1.

Answer (score 12):

The general idea of query languages is to express the **desired result**, not how to get it.

Applying it to your scenario leads to a simple query like this

```
var query = context.ParentTransaction
   .Where(t => t.PayAmount != context.ChildTransaction
      .Where(ct => ct.TransactionId == t.TransactionId)
      .Sum(ct => ct.DepositAmount));
```

If you are using **EF** and a proper model navigation properties, it would be even simple

```
var query = context.ParentTransaction
    .Where(t => t.PayAmount != t.ChildTransactions.Sum(ct => ct.DepositAmount));
```

One may say the above would be inefficient compared to let say the one from @Vadim Martynov answer. Well, may be yes, may be not. Vadim is trying to force a specific **execution plan** and I can understand that - we have to do such things when in reality encounter a query performance issues. But it's not natural and should be a last resort only if we have a performance problems. Query providers and SQL query optimizers will do (and are doing) that job for us in most of the cases, so we don't need to think of whether we need to use a `join` vs `subquery` etc.

Comment: can you show me sql equivalent query for this please

Comment: @Learning Add `var sql = query.ToString();`, run in VS debugger, put a breakpoint and examine `sql` variable in Locals/Watch window with Text Visualizer.

Comment: have you looked at vadim query.can you tell me something about it because i havent understand anything in his query

Comment: Yes I did. It's correct and alternative way to produce the same result. But that's the main point in my post, when looking at query it's hard to understand what it is doing. You can use Intellisense and MSDN documentation to understand it, but basically it creates a subsuqery that groups child transtactions by `TrasactionId` and calculates sum of the `DebitAmout`, then joins that subquery to `ParentTransaction` table to get the final result.

Comment: yes his query is correct but really hard to understand what he is doing is his query

Comment: In your query how do i select fieilds from my parenttransaction table?

Comment: The way I wrote it, it returns all the fields from `ParentTransaction` table, that's why no special select is needed.

Comment: I am talking about your first query

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100458/discussion-between-learning-and-ivan-stoev).

Answer (score 8):

I'm not sure that `!=` is a best value. Here is a solution with `>` check and grouping:

```
var expectedValue =
            context.ChildTransaction
                .GroupBy(t => t.TransactionId, (key, group) => new { TransactionId = key, Deposit = group.Sum(e => e.Deposit) })
                .Join(context.ParentTransaction, grouped => grouped.TransactionId, transaction => transaction.TransactionId, (group, transaction) => new { Transaction = transaction, group.Deposit })
                .Where(result => result.Transaction.PayAmount > result.Deposit)
                .Select(result => result.Transaction);
```

This query can be read in a declare manner like next requirement:

1. [Group](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673(v=sql.120).aspx) collection of child transactions by `TransactionId` and for each group retrieve an [anonymous type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx) object with fields TransactionId = grouping  key (== TransactionId) and Deposit which is sum of Deposits for rows with same TransactionId.
2. [Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191472.aspx) set from part 1 to the the table `PaerntTransaction` by `TransactionId` field. For each joined pair retrieve an [anonymous type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx) object with fields Transaction == transaction from `ParentTransactions` table and Deposit which is deposit from part 1 set which is sum of Deposits with the same `TransactionId` from the `ChildTransactions` table.
3. Filter from result set only objects where PayAmount greather than sum of deposits.
4. Return only `ParentTransaction` object for each filtered row.

This is SQL-optimized scenario because join, filter and grouping prevents [nested queries](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189575(v=sql.105).aspx) which can be added to the actual execution plan in other cases and make worse performance.

**UPDATE**

To solve the problem with transaction that have no deposits you can use [LEFT JOIN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397895.aspx):

```
var expectedValue = from parent in context.ParentTransaction
            join child in context.ChildTransaction on parent.TransactionId equals child.TransactionId into gj
            from subset in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
            let joined = new { Transaction = parent, Deposit = subset != null ? subset.Deposit : 0 }
            group joined by joined.Transaction
            into grouped
            let g = new { Transaction = grouped.Key, Deposit = grouped.Sum(e => e.Deposit) }
            where g.Transaction.PayAmount > g.Deposit
            select g.Transaction;
```

The same query with LINQ method chain:

```
var expectedValue =
            context.ParentTransaction
                .GroupJoin(context.ChildTransaction, parent => parent.TransactionId, child => child.TransactionId, (parent, gj) => new { parent, gj })
                .SelectMany(@t => @t.gj.DefaultIfEmpty(), (@t, subset) => new { @t, subset })
                .Select(@t => new { @t, joined = new { Transaction = @t.@t.parent, Deposit = @t.subset != null ? @t.subset.Deposit : 0 } })
                .GroupBy(@t => @t.joined.Transaction, @t => @t.joined)
                .Select(grouped => new { grouped, g = new { Transaction = grouped.Key, Deposit = grouped.Sum(e => e.Deposit) } })
                .Where(@t => @t.g.Transaction.PayAmount > @t.g.Deposit)
                .Select(@t => @t.g.Transaction);
```

Now you retrieve all parent transaction and join it with child transaction but if there is no children then use `Deposit == 0` and group joined entities in a similar manner by `ParentTransaction`.

Comment: can you please explain me your query.please

Comment: Thank you so so much sir for an awsome query.i was really struggling alot to do this.Cant even thank you because thank you would be so small to thank you.

Comment: when i am adding 1 transaction in parent transaction whose entry is not there in child transaction so that transaction is unpaid right.for Eg:Transaction id:4 so that transaction with id:4 is not coming with your query.See my updated input

Comment: @Learning yes there was an issue. I updated my answer with left join example an extra link to MSDN.

Comment: Wait let me test your query but thanks for updating your answer

Comment: Your above query is for getting all unpaid transaction.Can i use your same query to get all paid transaction.I mean those transaction whose full payment has been done.For eg:transactionId 1 and 2

Comment: @Learning of course, just change WHERE expression in your query to @t => `@t.g.Transaction.PayAmount == @t.g.Deposit` or `@t.g.Transaction.PayAmount <= @t.g.Deposit`

Comment: Sorry your query for getting all paid transaction is not working.so i guess this will not work with getting all unpaid transaction too.I have tried this one:ar expectedValue = from parent in context.ParentTransaction

Comment: Nice set-oriented solution. IMO, when creating SQL queries you get better results when you think in terms of filtering/combining sets of records, rather than considering all the conditions of a single record (if you see what I mean).  And I think it is rather optimistic of some people to think that query optimizers will find for themselves transformations of record-oriented queries into set-oriented queries (i.e., changing nested queries to joins).  (But on that last point I'm willing to be corrected by anyone knowledgeable.)

Answer (score 4):

### Problem

The issue lies on this statement:

```
where tmp.PayAmount != tmp1.DepositAmount //the culprit
```

And since the `tmp1` is defined as a **single** child transaction, the statement would result in equating wrong values:

**Visualizer**:

```
1000 != 600 //(result: true -> selected) comparing parent 1 and child 1
1000 != 400 //(result: true -> selected) comparing parent 1 and child 2
3000 != 1000 //(result: true -> selected) comparing parent 2 and child 3
3000 != 1000 //(result: true -> selected) comparing parent 2 and child 4
3000 != 1000 //(result: true -> selected) comparing parent 2 and child 5
5000 != 2000 //(result: true -> selected) comparing parent 2 and child 5
//However, you do not want it to behave like this actually
```

But what you want to have is rather:

**Visualizer**:

```
1000 != (600 + 400) //(result: false -> not selected) comparing parent 1 and child 1 & 2, based on the TransactionId
3000 != (1000 + 1000 + 1000) //(result: false -> not selected) comparing parent 2 and child 3, 4, & 5, based on the TransactionId
5000 != (2000)  //(result: true -> selected) comparing parent 3 and child 6, based on the TransactionId 
6000 != nothing paid //(result: true -> selected) comparing parent 3 with the whole childTransaction and found there isn't any payment made
```

Thus, you should make `tmp1` is as a **collection** of children rather than **single** child.

---

### Solution

#### Unpaid Transaction

Change your code like this:

```
var data = (from tmp in context.ParentTransaction
            join tmp1 in context.ChildTransaction.GroupBy(x => x.TransactionId) //group this by transaction id
            on tmp.TransactionId equals tmp1.Key //use the key
            where tmp.PayAmount > tmp1.Sum(x => x.DepositAmount) //get the sum of the deposited amount
            select tmp)
           .Union( //added after edit
           (from tmp in context.ParentTransaction
            where !context.ChildTransaction.Select(x => x.TransactionId).Contains(tmp.TransactionId)
            select tmp)
           );
```

---

**Explanations**

This line:

```
join tmp1 in context.ChildTransaction.GroupBy(x => x.TransactionId) //group this by transaction id
```

Making use of `GroupBy` in `Linq`, this line makes `tmp1` a **group** of children rather than a **single** child and, rightfully, based on its foreign key, which is the `TransactionId`.

Then this line:

```
on tmp.TransactionId equals tmp1.Key //use the key
```

We simply equates `tmp.TransactionId` with the children's group key `tmp1.Key`

Then the next line:

```
where tmp.PayAmount > tmp1.Sum(x => x.DepositAmount) //get the sum of the deposited amount
```

Get the sum value of the children's `DepositAmount` rather than single child's `DepositAmount` which is less than the `PayAmount` in the parent, and then

```
select tmp
```

Select all the parent transactions which satisfy all the criteria above. This way, we are half-done.

The next step is to consider transaction which occurs in the parent but not in the child(ren). This is considered as unpaid too.

We can combine the result of the first `query` with the second `query` using `Union`

```
.Union( //added after edit
(from tmp in context.ParentTransaction
 where !context.ChildTransaction.Select(x => x.TransactionId).Contains(tmp.TransactionId)
 select tmp)
);
```

This selects whatever exist in the parent transaction but doesn't exist at all in the child (and therefore considered unpaid).

And you would get the right `data`, consisting of your `ParentTransaction` rows which are not fully paid, both for the parent transaction whose `TransactionId` exists in the child or not.

---

#### Paid Transaction

As for the paid transaction, simply change the query from `>` to `<=`:

```
var datapaid = (from tmp in context.ParentTransaction
                join tmp1 in context.ChildTransaction.GroupBy(y => y.TransactionId)
                on tmp.TransactionId equals tmp1.Key
                where tmp.PayAmount <= tmp1.Sum(x => x.DepositAmount)
                select tmp);
```

---

#### Combined

We can further simplify the above query like this:

```
var grp = context.ChildTransaction.GroupBy(y => y.TransactionId);
var data = (from tmp in context.ParentTransaction
            join tmp1 in grp //group this by transaction id
            on tmp.TransactionId equals tmp1.Key //use the key
            where tmp.PayAmount > tmp1.Sum(x => x.DepositAmount)
            select tmp)
            .Union((
            from tmp in context.ParentTransaction
            where !context.ChildTransaction.Select(x => x.TransactionId).Contains(tmp.TransactionId)
            select tmp));

var datapaid = (from tmp in context.ParentTransaction
                join tmp1 in grp
                on tmp.TransactionId equals tmp1.Key
                where tmp.PayAmount <= tmp1.Sum(x => x.DepositAmount)
                select tmp);
```

Comment: Can you tell me what is the difference between your query and D Mayuri query as because i have already tried D Mayuri query which is not working

Comment: @Learning I haven't tried D. Mayuri. But I have tried my own query and it works well. Give me a while, I would try it out. And meanwhile, you could also try mine...

Comment: Yeah sure i will definetely try your query but please do consider the cases which i have describe on Vadim answers.See my comments on vadim answer

Comment: @Learning aah, I see. you also want to get the transaction 4 which has no pay at all... I shall update my answer..

Comment: I just want to get all unpaid transaction.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101038/discussion-between-learning-and-ian).

Answer (score 2):

```
List<int> obj = new List<int>();
using (DemoEntities context = new DemoEntities())
{
    obj = (from ct in context.CTransactions
    group ct by ct.Transactionid into grp
    join pt in context.PTransactions on grp.Key equals pt.Transactionid
    where grp.Sum(x => x.DepositAmount) < pt.PayAmount
    select grp.Key).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind efforts towards helping me.

Answer (score 2):

You control only one child transaction. You must use `Sum()` operation and need to use `>` instead of `!=` Pls try this.

```
var data = (from tmp in context.ParentTransaction
            join tmp1 in context.ChildTransaction on tmp.Transactionid equals into tmp1List
            tmp1.Transactionid where tmp.PayAmount > tmp1List.Sum(l => l.DepositAmount)
            select tmp);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind efforts towards helping me.

Comment: No problem mate. I hope this answer helped to you.